# SQLAlchemy fails to install

Tags: python, pip

Running the command

```sh
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

returns the following error:

```
Collecting SQLAlchemy
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.3.15.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\joão coelho\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\joão coelho\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\JOOCOE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpsg3pneho'
         cwd: C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sjum2aoe\SQLAlchemy
    Complete output (15 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\requires.txt 
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'  
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'  
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: unexpected end of data (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build\output'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'  
    creating 'C:\Users\João Coelho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ojxrdbjo\SQLAlchemy.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\joão coelho\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\joão coelho\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\JOOCOE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpsg3pneho' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It seems like a character that isn't supported by UTF-8?! Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Is it coming because of `Jo[ã]o Coelho`? Anyway we need to change the encoding?

Comment: @user27286 Probably that is the cause. How can I change the encoding?

Comment: Have you tried installing any other package using `pip`?

Comment: Yes, and they installed succesfully.

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: @AMC wich information do you need? (sorry I'm a noob)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you might try downloading "SQLAlchemy-1.3.15-cp38-cp38-win32.whl" from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sqlalchemy) and then run:

```
pip install C:\your\path\to\SQLAlchemy-1.3.15-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

[Github Credit](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5219)